# Large Green Circle Emoji is not being displayed

Tags: unicode, osx-el-capitan

My browser and apps are not displaying the Large Green Circle Emoji   [unicode 1F7E2].

Instead, the following is being displayed [image] .

I would appreciate some help in fixing this.

I am using a MacBook Pro OSX 10.11.6

<sup>Post edited to show both Unicode for those who cannot see it & image of missing glyph for those who can.

Even so, some may see the missing glyph as an empty square, or a square with a question mark. This is very much OS-dependent.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

That character set is not present in OS X 10.11 - El Capitan
It's not even present in 10.14 - Mojave

I'm not sure when it was added, but it is in macOS 12 - Monterey

Mojave

> [image]

Monterey

> [image]

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to 'add' it other than by updating your OS [which will likely not be possible].

Screenshots from both OSes…

Mojave

> [image]

Monterey

> [image]

Comment: oh thats a shame // i thought there would have been a workaround ... :(

Comment: No, sorry - I'm even surprised you can still see this entire page correctly in El Cap. What browser are you using? Safari's no good any more from that long ago. This is what I see using El Cap [I have VMs of many older macOS versions for testing] - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaeaS.png BTW, El Cap is really not safe to be online with any more.

Comment: Lol ..It's an old laptop. The most it can upgrade to is El Captain.